# Law of demeter -- need for internal representation?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Imagine we have a class "NeuralNetwork"

- Each NeuralNetwork consists of layers
- Each Layer consists of neurons
- Each neurons consists of weights, a bias and an activation function

  ```
  class Neuron:
      def __init__(self,weights,bias,activation):
          self._weights = weights
          self._bias = bias
          self._activation = activation

      def activate(self,input):
          return self._activation.compute(self._weights.dot(input)+self._bias)


  class Layer:
      def __init__(self,neurons):
          self._neurons = neurons

      def compute(self,input):
          output = []
          for neuron in self._neurons:
              output.append(neuron.activate(input))
          return output


  class NeuralNetwork:
      def __init__(self,layers):
          self._layers = layers

      def compute(self,input):
          output = input
          for layer in self._layers:
              output = layer.compute(output)
          return output

      def train(self,dataset):
          # do some training
          # changes the neurons inside the layers
  ```

NeuralNetwork has a method train() that changes its internal representation.
But this means having access to the internals of the Layer objects. It needs access to the individual neurons, breaking the law of demeter.
for example

```
layers[0].getNeuron(0).compute(input)

layer[0].getNeuron(0).changeBias(2)
```

The only solution I can think of is to provide extra methods in "Layer" and delegate it to the neurons. This would also allow me to use different implementations of a Layer interface. One which is more flexible and one that has better performance.

But this seems cumbersome. Isn't there a better way to model this?

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear how `train` picks up which neurons to modify. But that aside, I suspect the observer pattern could provide a possible alternative. Neurons would subscribe to events on layers, and `train` would publish events to layers. That way, layers would be a "dump" intermediate, the actual handling in neurons, while keeping law of demeter.

Comment: But this would introduce a circular dependency since layers still need to know about neurons to compute its output. So since everything is published to the layer I see not advantage above simple providing methods that delegate. I've added a diagram describing my problem. It is the dependency between Network and Neuron that I want removed.


How the train method works is irrelevant. It basically does some computations and changes the weights of all individual neurons.

Comment: Neurons wouldn't know about layers. Layers would subscribe them and call their event handling method, much like how it calls their `activate()` method in your code now. The link between `Network` and `Neuron` would be broken, and `Layer` wouldn't need to provide any wrapper methods, only one for delegating events to neurons.

Comment: So something like this? 
`train()` assembles an `Event` object with a particular neuron "address" and publishes it to a layer `layer.publish(event)`. Now layer might broadcast this to all the neurons or parse it partially, discover the address and send it to the correct neuron `neuron.parse(event)`.

Comment: So what if you break the law of Demeter? It's only a guideline. Excess dependencies/coupling (breaking the law of Demeter) is bad because changes to the things on which other things depend can propagate detrimentally. How "unstable" is `Neuron`? If you're willing to live with it being stable, then don't worry about Law of Demeter.

Comment: @AmrMostafa I wouldn't apply Observer unless there was a need to add in the future other types of observers AND you want to decouple. Observer is designed for BOTH conditions.

Comment: @kevinhendrickx IMHO observer would provide a nice abstraction only if `train()` publishes to neurons matching certain criteria or that art part of a certain group, not by their "addrss" or index. If it must know the "address" of each single neuron then observer adds complexity without providing much value

Answer (score 1):

The first possible solution is to just add some methods that delegate.

A second solution, extracted from Amr Mostafa's comments would be to send an event through the Layer object to the neurons.

Both solutions would allow us to use a different Layer object which consists out of multidimensional arrays instead of neuron objects (performance consideration).

[image]

Comment: This breaks the KISS pattern. Designs are trade offs. If you feel the extra complexity of these solutions mitigates the risk of Neurons changing its methods radically (the reason Law of Demeter is called into play), then go for it. Personally, I'd live with the simpler model and wait for some pain and suffering from instability before I add all this event complexity. You'll have to live with it when you debug, and remember its complexity months later when you want to change something.